# GCD: Functions or Blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

While using [grand-central-dispatch](/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch), is there a benefit or disadvantage of using blocks over functions or vice versa?

Essentially if we are using *GCD* whats the best mode to execute tasks, blocks or functions? Is there any specific case where a particular mode should be used? I'm interested in knowing from all perspective. Performance, cleaner code etc.

Thanks

Comment: Narrow the question a little down in terms what you like to know, currently the question is way to broad.

Comment: usually blocks are the way to go, since its easier to follow your codes logic, and also can capture the scopes variables automatically, instead of having to pass them as parameters to a function. but all depends really... doubt there is an significant performance difference between the two either

Comment: @Leandros OK. So to simplify I am wondering if I'm using GCD, will it be beneficial to use blocks over functions or vice versa? Maybe at a generic level the question would be does blocks or functions offer any edge over the other in the context of GCD. And how?... Not sure if it made it any simpler!!

Comment: @0x6d6e blocks don't have anything to do with GCD.